# Parse XML subitems using foreach()

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an XML file that needs parsing in PHP.  I am currenlty using simplexml_load_file to load the file like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Project.xml');
```

Inside that XML file lies a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project>
<name>Project 1</name>
<features>
    <feature>Feature 1</feature>
    <feature>Feature 2</feature>
    <feature>Feature 3</feature>
    <feature>Feature 4</feature>
</features>
</project>
```

What I am trying to do is print the `<name>` contents along with EACH `<feature>` element within `<features>`.  I'm not sure how to do this because there is more than 1 element called `<feature>`.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to print the text, try this :

```
foreach($xml->features->feature as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simplexml_load_file() returns an object.

Have a look at the structure with var_dump($xml):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "Project 1"
  ["features"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["feature"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Feature 1"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "Feature 2"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "Feature 3"
      [3]=>
      string(9) "Feature 4"
    }
  }
}
```

So code like this:

```
<?PHP
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo $xml->name . "\n";
foreach($xml->features->feature as $f){
  echo "\t$f\n";
}
```

Will produce output like:

```
Project 1
    Feature 1
    Feature 2
    Feature 3
    Feature 4
```

Which is what I assume you're after, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
foreach($xml->features->feature as $f) {
    echo $f."\n";
}
```